# flutter_facebook_auth plugin not clearing the data when logging out

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, flutter-facebook-login

I'm making use of the `flutter_facebook_auth 3.5.0` plugin to enable users to log into my app using their Facebook account.

Everything is working as expected. But when I log out and try to login again, it isn't prompting me to enter the credentials and directly logs me in.

I want it to prompt the user to enter their Facebook account credentials and then log into the app only if the authentication was successful.

Below is the SignIn code:

```
Future<void> signInWithFacebook(BuildContext context) async {
    User? firebaseUser;
    LoginResult response = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
    AuthCredential facebookCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.accessToken!.token);
    final UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
    firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
    switch (response.status) {
      case LoginStatus.success:
        final userData = await FacebookAuth.instance.getUserData();
        facebookUserData = userData;
        firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc(firebaseUser!.uid).set({
          "userID": firebaseUser.uid,
          "name": facebookUserData["name"],
          "photo": facebookUserData["picture"]["data"]["url"],
          "emailAddress": facebookUserData["email"],
          "signUpMethod": "facebook",
          "accountCreatedOn": Timestamp.now(),
          "receiveOffers": true,
          "isAdmin": false,
          "isAuth": false,
          "isSubscribed": false,
        });
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(ScaledAnimationPageRoute(HomePage()));
        break;
      case LoginStatus.cancelled:
        print("Facebook: User cancelled login");
        break;
      case LoginStatus.failed:
        print("Facebook: Login error!");
        break;
      case LoginStatus.operationInProgress:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
        break;
    }
  }
```

Below is the method for logout:

```
await FacebookAuth.instance.logOut();
      facebookUserData = {};
      await authInstance.signOut().then((value) => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(ScaledAnimationPageRoute(SignIn())));
```

I think the `AuthCredential` needs to be cleared when the user is logging out. I'm not sure how to do it.

I'm new to Flutter. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you got the solution for above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an issue on the github project of the `flutter_facebook_auth 3.5.0` [here](https://github.com/darwin-morocho/flutter-facebook-auth/issues/62#issuecomment-799895330).

It looks like an lmitation of Facebook and not the plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use package named flutter_facebook_login instead...I am using this package and it is working well